# How to install xml.dom.minidom in python

Tags: python, installation

I would like to install minidom but I don't know how. Is it part of PyXML?

I have tried to use easy install with PyXML but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `it doesn't seem to work`? What went wrong?

Comment: it can't install it, it says extensions/pyexpat.c:5:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @user2040597 You should not even need to, its a part of the python standard library, see my answer.

Comment: but when I use import xml.dom.minidom, if I execute my code, I get ImportError: No module named dom.minidom

Comment: You might have called your own script `xml.py` and that would shadow the XML package from the standard library. Can you show us the full traceback please?

Answer (score 6):

Ahh, you don't need PyXML to use it, it's included in the standard library.

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> help(xml.dom.minidom)

Help on module xml.dom.minidom in xml.dom:

NAME
    xml.dom.minidom - Simple implementation of the Level 1 DOM.

DESCRIPTION
    Namespaces and other minor Level 2 features are also supported.

    parse("foo.xml")

    parseString("<foo><bar/></foo>")

    Todo:
    =====
     * convenience methods for getting elements and text.
     * more testing
     * bring some of the writer and linearizer code into conformance with this
            interface
     * SAX 2 namespaces
...
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is a part of the [Python standard Library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).